# Валидность кода на php

Tags: php

Добрый день! Хочу сделать след образом, есть два поля логин и пароль, хочу что бы человек ввел логин и пароль регистрировался (это упрощенный вариант кончено там будет куча проверок и полей). Так вот меня интересует как сделать проверку поля по след алгоритму:

1. Человек заполняет поле.
2. Данный переходят методом $_POST в файл обработчик check.php
3. Подключаюсь к баззе, выгружаю данные из таблицы users сохраняю массив.
4. Прохожусь по массиву и проверяю с переданным параметром $_POST[логин] существет ли логин
5. Если существует то вернулся на страницу и показал ошибку такой пользователь существует.

Подскажите как сделать 5 пункт, не получается никак сделать, может как то алгоритм поменять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гораздо более эффективно будет перевалить эту работу на бд (проверку присутствия логина в базе данных). Самый простой пример:

```
$q = "select COUNT(*) from users where login='".$_POST['login']."'";
```

Comment: Инъекция...

Comment: @ModaL в данном примере я принебрег фильтрацией данных, так как каждый php разработчик должен быть параноиком и фильтровать все что приходит от пользователя)

Comment: или должен перестать использовать параметризованные запросы... в смысле ваша ошибка не в том что вы не фильтруете данные, а в том, что вы создали запрос текстовой строкой.

Answer (score 0):

Ты будь проще!

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']);
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`="'.$name.'" AND `pwd`="'.$pwd.'"');
if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0) echo 'Нет такого пользователя';
else{
$user=mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo 'Здравствуйте, '.$user['name'].'! Ваш пароль: '.$user['pwd'].'.';
```

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: пока что оно не удалено. Да и суть особо не меняется - просто "i" всем командам добавить.

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_prepare::php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
Сделает все круто и заэкранирует. Кошерный вариант, подвешенный на плейсхолдерах.